# Deploying database-first C# ASP.NET MVC app - connect to different database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm trying to deploy a database-first application I have created. I'm using an `.edmx` file for the models. I've been using a local db for testing and building but now I'm to the point where I need to demo and get feedback. In order to deploy it, I changed the connection string to:

```
<add name="Entities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBModels.csdl|res://*/Models.DBModels.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=CRMS;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

So that it would connect to the new database. However, this doesn't work and I get a metadata path is not valid error.

This is my first database-first app. I supposed I could create another `.edmx` file based off the production database but there has to be an easier way.

Comment: Since you are going to a different database, did you push the migration to the new database yet? Also, I have never seen a connection string quite like this, with the metadata= in it. What kind of database are you trying to move to?

Comment: @PatrickMcvay Not a migration so much as changing the connection string for the DB project to point to the production database and rerunning that project.  I'm going from a localdb file to a full-blown MS SQL installation

Comment: @PatrickMcvay: it's an Entity Framework connection string - see the providerName: `System.Data.EntityClient` - this is for EF 1.x/4.x with the model-based `.edmx` file. But the connection string looks OK to me - **if** that's the right server and database name. Have you created that database on that server?

Comment: @marc_s Yes, that is the correct servername.  I copy/pasted the connection string from the properties window after connecting to it from the server explorer

Answer (score 0):

I met with a similar error but I ended up creating another .edmx file because sometimes there will be issues with EF internally when you try to move/change and rerun it.

Try these links, might help solve the problem: [Link-1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2d6f829-0703-47cc-b23a-25f563c25712/adonet-entity-framwork-the-specified-metadata-path-is-not-valid?forum=adodotnetentityframework) [Link-2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/cc716677(v=vs.100))